# How to iterate two arrays both containing custom classes simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift

lets say you have the classes:

```
class Artwork {
 var title = ""
 var location =""
 var author = ""
}

class GroupedArtworks {
    var location = ""
    var artworks = [Artworks]()
}
```

then you have an variable that contains several objects of the class "Artwork":

```
var arts = [artwork1, artwork2...]
```

How would I group the objects of the class "Artwork" by "location"?

I would like to end up with another variable containing objects of the class "GroupedArtworks"
and for each object, in the attribute "artworks" have all the objects that have the same "location"
so something like:

```
var orderedArtworks = [groupedartworks1, groupedartworks2...]
```

No doubt for loops are involved here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is super easy with Swift's Dictionary `init(grouping:by:)`

```swift
let artworks: [Artwork] = []
// dictionary type will be [String: [Artwork]]
let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: artworks, by: \.location)

// now we can easy iterate over (key: String, value: [Artwork]) pairs
let groups: [GroupedArtworks] = dictionary.map { location, artworks in
    GroupedArtworks(location: location, artworks: artworks)
}
// or simply
let groups = dictionary.map(GroupedArtworks.init)
// Swift will infer the types of dictionary and the init
```

but you will need to add this init to your `GroupedArtworks`

```swift
class GroupedArtworks {

    let location: String
    let artworks: [Artwork]

    init(location: String, artworks: [Artwork]) {
        self.location = location
        self.artworks = artworks
    }
    
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init)

As someone correctly pointed out in the comments, since dicts are unordered collections, your array of `GroupedArtworks` will be unordered one as-well. But this should not be a problem since you can easily sort it by lets say `location`.

```swift
let groups = dictionary.map(GroupedArtworks.init).sorted(by: \.location)
```

Comment: good point, I have now mentioned that in my answer

Comment: a lot of unnecessary typing. Swift is a type inferred language. `let groups = dictionary.map(GroupedArtworks.init)`

Comment: Sure, I know that. Since the answer is meant to be educational I just want to emphasise the result of each call. Should be easier to grasp for someone unfamiliar with the API

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus for suggestion, I have update the answer with yours short `map` call